# Mysql updating timestamp with curdate

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm working with Perl and Mysql, I testing this query in Navicat

```
UPDATE table SET times = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE id = 1;
```

Example, when I exec in Navicat, I get result 2014-06-18 00:00:00
When I exec this query from perl script, I get 2014-06-18 15:22:12
Why in perl script not 00:00:00 ?
column times have type timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I think the perl connector (DBI) is adding in the current time (Hh:mm:ss), whereas Navicat's connector does not. My suggestion would be to use **NOW()** instead of **CURDATE()**, which should solve this problem.

[image: MySQL Dates]

Alternatively if you want it to be 00:00:00, then try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY
```

Comment: Try the date_format and see if that makes a difference, otherwise you may need to build the string yourself using date_format plus an append "00:00:00"

Comment: Any success @user1144700 ?

Comment: I'm stupid, i run other version of perl-script, where usage NOW();